# Add colon (:) as part of query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have column name which contains `:` so, when query is executed then it does not return result but fails and give error. How can i add colon `:` as part of query?
E.g

```
SELECT
  M.Id,
  M.Name,
  M.Salery,
  M.Sheet11:Id,
  M.Role
FROM
  `data_root`.`MergeR` M
```

Comment: escape the colon using `\\`

Comment: Don't use colon for Column names. Just use - or _

Comment: It will be better if you rename your column name

Comment: Which DBMS do you use?

Comment: The column name is generated automatically so i can not edit one.

Comment: And the reason for adding : is to have unique name generated where if i add "_" then there might be possibility that name might be present in DB.

Comment: Added `mysql` tag based on the usage of the backtick `\`` in the `from` clause

Comment: @Ganesh Why not use a prefix then? Like 'tbl'?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
   SELECT
      M.Id,
      M.Name,
      M.Salery,
      M.[Sheet11:Id],
      M.Role
    FROM Table M
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
SELECT
  M.Id,
  M.Name,
  M.Salery,
  M.`Sheet11:Id`, 
  M.Role
FROM
  `data_root`.`MergeR` M
```

If no luck, check this:

```
SELECT
  M.Id,
  M.Name,
  M.Salery,
  M."Sheet11:Id", 
  M.Role
FROM
  `data_root`.`MergeR` M
```

If we know the model of the database we will be able to help more!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  M.Id,
  M.Name,
  M.Salery,
  M.[Sheet11:Id],
  M.Role
FROM
  `data_root`.`MergeR` M
```

The above will work. Square brackets are used because : is a special character. It is used as a bind variable in SQL. Putting it as **M.[Sheet11:Id]** means it will be used as a normal character and NOT as the SQL special character.

Answer (score -1):

Normally the colon is used in SQL for binding variables. This is a good way to prevent SQL injection. When using the colon you are using Prepared Statements:

[Prepared Statements in PHP and SQL](http://docs.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements)